# $n^5-n$ is divisible by $10$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I was trying to prove this, and I realized that this is essentially a statement that $n^5$ has the same last digit as $n$, and to prove this it is sufficient to calculate $n^5$ for $0-9$ and see that the respective last digits match. Another approach I tried is this: I factored $n^5-n$ to $n(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$. If $n$ is even, a factor of $2$ is guaranteed by the factor $n$. If $n$ is odd, the factor of $2$ is guaranteed by $(n^2+1)$. The factor of $5$ is guaranteed if the last digit of $n$ is $1, 4, 5, 6,$ $or$ $9$ by the factors $n(n+1)(n-1)$, so I only have to check for $n$ ending in digits $0, 2, 3, 7,$ $and$ $8$.  However, I'm sure that there has to be a much better proof (and without modular arithmetic). Do you guys know one? Thanks!

Comment: Removing number theory tags as modular arithmetic is not allowed.

Comment: Whether or not modular arithmetic is allowed, it is still a question of elementary number theory.

Comment: @MJD If one cannot use the basic tools of number theory, it shouldn't be tagged as such.

Comment: One has to use *other* basic tools of number theory, and that's what the answers below demonstrate.

Comment: It's arguable whether the answers below use tools of number theory or algebraic manipulations.

Comment: It's funny to ask for a proof about modular arithmetic which does not use modular arithmetic.

Comment: I've never understood people who ask for answerers to not use modular arithmetic. The answers invariably end up using modular arithmetic and just not using the word 'mod,' because that's essentially the only way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Potato is there modular arithmetic in my answer? I only appealed to the idea that if we have a formula that is a sum of some terms, and some of them are clearly divisible by ten, then those terms have no effect on the divisibility by 10 of the overall formula. Clearly, that is linked to congruences: when set aside those terms that are divisible by 10, we are of course manipulating the formula in such a way that it stays congruent to the same value modulo 10. Just there are no formal trappings of congruences.

Comment: @Kaz That's exactly what I mean. You are doing modular arithmetic, but not formally.

Comment: @Potato I updated my answer with a "full disclosure", because basically even the little step of arguing that $k(k + 1)(k + 1)$ is even depends on congruences! Division into even/odd cases is tantamount to division into the two symbols of the mod 2 congruence. Divisibility is tied to congruences, period. This question boils down to "prove that such and such a formula is congruent to 0 mod 10, but don't use congruences or modulo math".

Comment: @Potato The reason why I ask people not to use modular arithmetic is because I don't know it. I might understand the concepts like the ones Kaz showed but I have no idea about the notation.

Comment: @Ovi It's really not that hard! You should learn it -- it will take 10 minutes. I can provide a reference if you need it.

Comment: @Potato: Yea I will please provide the reference

Comment: @Ovi http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~erowland/modulararithmetic.html

Comment: @Potato Thank you very much!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your proof is good enough. There's a slight improvement, if you want to avoid modular arithmetic / considering cases.

$n^5 - n$ is a multiple of 5 
$\Leftrightarrow$  $ n^5 + 10 n^4 + 35n^3 + 50 n^2 + 24 n = n^5 -n + 5(2n^4 + 7n^3 + 10n^2 + 5n) $ is a multiple of 5. The latter is just $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)$, which is the product of 5 consecutive integers, hence is a multiple of 5.

---

Note: You should generally be able to do the above transformation, and can take the product of any 5 (or k) consecutive integers, if you are looking at a polynomial of degree 5 (or k).

Comment: I don't understand the point of n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4) being divisible by 5, because n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4) does not equal $n^5−n$

Comment: @Ovi I made the if and only if implication explicit. Does this help?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see why n^5−n is a multiple of 5 ⇔ $n^5+10n+35n+50n+24n$. And if you are using $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)$, shouldn't it be $n^5+10n^4+35n^3+50n^2+24n?$

Comment: @Ovi Indeed, I forgot the degrees. I've added the explanation, though it's similar to the rest, which you seem to have trouble following. Do you agree with "$x$ is a multiple of 5 if and only if $x+5$ is a multiple of 5"?

Comment: @Ovi: Notice that adding $10n^4$ or $35n^3$ or $50n^2$ doesn't change divisibility by 5 because all of them are multiples of 5, and adding a multiple of 5 to a number already divisible by 5 will keep it divisible by 5, and adding a multiple of 5 to a number not divisible by 5 will keep it not divisible by 5. I think the problem is that everyone here knows and is implicitly stating the same result of modular arithmetic, which you aren't following, that 24n = -n (mod 5).

Comment: Oh ok thank you I see. My problem was understanding the 24n, but now I see that if n^5-n is divisible by 5, the 24n is too. Very nice solution.

Answer (score 12):

$$n^5-n=n(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)= n(n^2-4)(n+1)(n-1)+5n(n-1)(n+1)=(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)+5n(n-1)(n+1)$$

$(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$ is even and divisible by 5, since it is the product of 5 consecutive integers.

$5(n-1)n(n+1)$ is also even and divisible by $5$.

**Note:** Both expressions are also divisible by $3$, so $n^5-n$ is actually divisible by $30$!

Comment: 265252859812191058636308480000000 does not divide $n^5-n$ :)

Comment: @cyclochaotic :))

Answer (score 6):

Clearly, $n$ and $n^5$ are of the same parity. Hence, $2 \vert (n^5-n)$.

To check for divisibility by $5$, note that
\begin{align}
n^5 - n & = (n^2+1)n(n+1)(n-1)\\
& = (n^2-4+5)n(n+1)(n-1)\\
& = (n^2-4)n(n+1)(n-1) + 5n(n+1)(n-1)\\
& = (n-2)(n-1)n (n+1)(n+2) + 5n(n+1)(n-1)\\
\end{align}

Clearly, $5 \vert 5n(n+1)(n-1)$. Also, $(n-2)(n-1)n (n+1)(n+2)$ is a product of $5$ consecutive numbers and hence $5$ divides it.

Comment: I don't understand the point of (n−2)(n−1)n(n+1)(n+2) being divisible by 5, because (n−2)(n−1)n(n+1)(n+2) does not equal $n^5-n$

Comment: $n^5-n=p+q$, thus $5|p$ and $5|q$ imply that $5|(n^5-n)$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $n$ and $n^5$ have the same parity, $f(n):=n^5-n$ is divisible by $2$. It is also divisible by $5$, since $f(0)=0$ and $f(n+1)-f(n)=\dotsc=5 n (n^3 + 2 n^2 + 2 n + 1)$. More generally, for every prime $p$, $f(n):=n^p-n$ is divisible by $p$, this is [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). In fact, $f(n+1)-f(n)=\sum_{0<k<p} \binom{p}{k} n^k$ and $p \mid \binom{p}{k}$ for $0 < k < p$.

Comment: Very nice solution

Answer (score 3):

Without modular arithmetic? How about induction?

Base case: it is true for $n = 0$ since $0^5 - 0 = 0$. It is also true for $-1$ and $1$ since $-1^5 + 1 = 0$, and $1^5 - 1 = 0$. And it is true for $-2$ and $2$: $-2^5 + 2 = -30$ and $2^5 - 2 = 30$.

Inductive hypothesis: if it is true for $k$, it can be shown to be true for $k + 1$ or vice versa. We can work it from $k + 1$ to $k$, avoiding any "trap door" steps, so that all derivation works both ways.

$$(k + 1)^5 - (k + 1) = 10q$$

$$k^5 + 5k^4 + 10k^3 + 10k^2 + 5k + 1 - (k + 1) = 10q$$

Rearrange terms, cancel 1 and -1:

$$k^5 - k + 5k^4 + 10k^3 + 10k^2 + 5k = 10q$$

Isolate $k^5 - k$:

$$k^5 - k  = 5k^4 + 10k^3 + 10k^2 + 5k + 10q$$

Now we need to show that the right hand side is divisible by ten. We can do this as follows. First, rearrange some terms:

$$k^5 - k  = 5k^4 + 10k^2 + 5k + 10k^3 + 10q$$

Now note that $10k^3$ and $10q$ are divisible by 10, the latter having come from our inductive hypothesis. So let us focus on the remaining terms, which comprise this formula:

$$5k^4 + 10k^2 + 5k$$

We can show that this is divisible by 10 by factoring out $5k$:

$$5k(k^2 + 2k + 1)$$

$$5k(k + 1)(k + 1)$$

But $k(k + 1)(k + 1)$ is an even number, which, multiplied by 5 is divisible by 10.   To show that $k(k + 1)(k + 1)$ we divide into cases. If we suppose that $k$ is odd, then we have odd x even x even, which is even. If we suppose that $k$ is even, then we have even x odd x odd, which is even again.

So the inductive hypothesis is true. If $(k + 1)^5 - (k + 1)$ is  divisible by $10$, then so is $k^5 - k$, and vice versa. By induction from the base case in the positive and negative directions, it is true for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Modular arithmetic wasn't used, but one basic argument which was used is linked to modular arithmetic. Namely, the argument that some $N$ {is/isn't} is divisible by $10$, then $N + 10k (k \in \mathbb{Z})$ likewise {is/isn't} divisible by $10$. This is equivalent to the modular concept that $N$ is congruent to $N + 10k$ modulo $10$, but without the formal trappings. Furthermore the argument about the evenness of $k(k + 1)(k + 1)$ also relies on congruences in disguise. Division into even/odd cases is nothing more than division into the two symbols of the mod 2 congruence.
We cannot really even discuss divisibility without invoking ties to congruences. Divisibility by 10 *means* congruence to 0 mod 10.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 3):

**Key idea** $\ \ p\!-\!1\mid n\!-\!1\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a^n- a.\ $ **Proof** $\ $ Clear if $\,p\mid a.\,$  Else write $\, \color{#f0f}n = (p\!-\!1)k + 1.\,$

$\  \color{#0a0}{b\!-\!1\mid b^k\!-\!1}\,$ so $\,b = a^{p-1}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{p\mid} \color{#0a0}{a^{p-1}\!-\!1\mid (a^{(p-1)k}\!-\!1)}a = a^\color{#f0f}{\large n}\!-\!a\ $ by $\rm\color{#c00}{little\ Fermat}\ \ {\bf QED}$

So $\ p\!-\!1,q\!-\!1\mid n\!-\!1\,\Rightarrow\ p,q\mid a^n\!-a\,\Rightarrow\,pq\mid a^n\!-a,\,$ by $\,{\rm lcm}(p,q) = pq\,$ for $\,p\neq q\,$ primes. Yours is the special case $\ p = 2,\ q = 5,\ n = 5.$

The converse is also true, which yields the following generalization of little Fermat-Euler.

**Theorem** $\ \ $ For naturals $\ m,n > 1$

$$ m \mid a^n - a\ \ \ \text{for all }\ a\in\Bbb Z\iff m\ \text{ is squarefree, and prime } p\mid m\,\Rightarrow\, p-1\mid n- 1$$

Comment: @KeyIdeas How do you get to $b=a^{p-1}$? And what are the different colors supposed to indicate?

Answer (score 2):

To check if $n^5-n$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $5$, it suffices to check the five cases $n = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2$. Since the polynomial $n^5-n$ is odd, the sign is not important, and we need check only $0$, $1$, and $2$. The first two cases are trivial, and for the last case we calculate manually $32 - 2$ which is divisible by $5$.

Congruence modulo $3$ or modulo $2$ is similar (only involves the "trivial" cases).