# Why is it that, $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z},\ x^5 \equiv x \pmod{10}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Just playing around, I realized that $x^{5}\equiv x \pmod{10}$ for all integral $x$. Euler's theorem explains this for $x$ coprime with $10$, as for such $x$, $x^{4}\equiv 1$, but I don't know why this happens for other $x$. Also, how would this be generalized to other bases and powers?

Comment: Oh cool I didn't think you could put LaTeX in the title.

Comment: I don't understand the syntax, what does the $\equiv$ symbol mean?

Comment: same as [$n^5-n$ divisible by 10](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404157/n5-n-is-divisible-by-10).

Comment: The question was closed while composing my answer, so [I posted my answer in the linked duplicate.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/418947/78535) The answer shows why it is true much  more generally.

Answer (score 5):

We have $x^5 - x = x(x^2+1)(x-1)(x+1)$. Since one of $x$, $x - 1$ must be divisible by $2$, it follows that $x^5 - x$ is divisible by $2$.

Now by Fermat's little theorem, for all $x$:
$$
x^5 \equiv x \pmod 5
$$

We conclude that $x^5 - x$ is divisible by $2 \times 5 = 10$.

Answer (score 1):

A number is divisible by $10$ if and only if it is divisible by $2$ and $5.$ By Fermat's Little theorem we see that $x^5-x$ is divisible by $5,$ and it is easy to see that $x^5$ has the same parity as $x$ so it is divisible by $2$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

You really already answered your own question.  Euler's Thm, as you say, gives the identity for $x$ coprime to 10.  But using the Chinese Remainder Thm, you can using Euler mod 2 and 5 to get your overall result.

If you don't like this, then just show 0, 2 and 5 by hand and use Euler for the rest.