# Prove that ${n^5 - n}$ is divisible by 5

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

I need to prove by induction if ${n^5 - n}$ is divisible by 5 and I have no idea how I would do it.

I am trying to prove it for several hours now, I started with ${n^5 - n} \mod  5 = 0$ but then I realized that I have no idea how to use modulo for transformations.

The next thing I tried was $(5 + n)\frac{n^5 - n}5 = \frac{(n+1)^5 - n+1}5$ but it didn't get me anywhere.

How would you do it?

Comment: I know that you are asking for induction, but Fermat's little theorem provides the result directly

Comment: Don't use $\bmod$ as the remainder operation. Do modular arithmetic instead.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350675/prove-n5-n-is-divisible-by-5-by-induction

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404157/n5-n-is-divisible-by-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle f(n): n^5-n$ is divisible by $5$ holds true for $n=m$

$\displaystyle\implies 5\mid(m^5-m)$

Now, $\displaystyle f(m+1)-f(m)=(m+1)^5-(m+1)-(m^5-m)=\sum_{1\le r \le 4}\binom5 rm^r$ which is divisible by $5$

as each $\displaystyle\binom5r,1\le r\le4$ is divisible by $5$

Finally, establish the base case i.e., $n=1$

Generalization :

More generally prime $p$ divides $\displaystyle\binom pr$ (can you prove [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149707/divisibility-of-binomial-coefficients-by-primes)?) for $1\le r\le p$ or more genrally $p\not\mid r$

So, we can prove  $\displaystyle n^p-n$ will be divisible by $p$ (Fermat's [Little Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html))

Comment: Caution: indeed $\;p\;$ divides $\;\binom pr\;$ .... **for** $\;1<r<p\;$ (or also for $\;r>p\;$ if we define $\;r>p\implies \binom pr=0\;$ )

Comment: @DonAntonio, why "Caution"?

Comment: Because what you wrote is *not* true for any $\;r\;$ , @lab

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks for pointing out, the restriction I wrote in the special case, forgot to include in the general one

Comment: it *still* must be $\;r<p\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, for $r>p$ or $r<0, \binom pr=0,$ right?

Comment: Yes @lab, yet in the one before the last line in your answer it it is written $\;1\le r\le p\;$ instead of the correct $\;1\le r<p\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be any prime number. Consider the polynomial $f=X^p-X=X(X^{p-1}-1)\in \mathbb F_p[X].$ This polynomial is the zero function $\mathbb F_p\to\mathbb F_p$ if and only if $n^p-n$ is divisible by $p$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. Clearly $f(0)=0$ and $\mathbb F_p^\times$ is a group of order $p-1$ so for all $a\in\mathbb F_p^\times$ we have $a^{p-1}=1$. Now apply this to $p=5$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 5\!:\ n\equiv 0,\,\pm1,\,$ or $\, \pm2.\ $  $\ 0^5\!\equiv 0,\,\ (\pm1)^5\!\equiv \pm1,\,\ (\pm2)^5\!\equiv \pm32\equiv \pm2,\ $ so $\ n^5\!\equiv n.$

Answer (score 1):

You can always try brute force in case you are stuck otherwise:

$$(n+1)^5=1+5 n+10 n^2+10 n^3+5 n^4+n^5$$
$$(n+1)^5-(n+1)=4 n+10 n^2+10 n^3+5 n^4+n^5$$
$$(n+1)^5-(n+1)-\big(n^5-n\big)=5 n+10 n^2+10 n^3+5 n^4=5(n+2n^2+2n^3+n^4)$$

Answer (score 1):

Any natural number can be represented by $5k + q$, where $q = 0,1,2,3,4$. If we prove it for all mentioned $q$, then it will work with every natural.

$n^5 - n = n(n^4 - 1) = n(n - 1)(n + 1)(n^2 + 1)$.

By the nature of this expansion if we plug in $ n = 5k + q$,  where $ q =0,1,4$, we will  get something of the form $5k*f(k)$, which is divisible by $5$.

If $q = 2,3$, then $n(n-1)(n+1)$ will not return a multiple of $5$, so we look at $n^2 + 1$ :

$n^2 + 1 = (5k + q)^2 + 1 = 25k^2 + 10kq + q^2 + 1$

If $q = 2$, then $n^2 + 1 = 25k^2 + 20k + 5$

If $q = 3$, then $n^2 + 1 = 25k^2 + 20k + 10$

In both cases, the resulting coefficients are divisible by $5$. The polynomial is divisible by $5$, for all mentioned $q$. Thus the polynomial satisfies the required condition for all naturals.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to give you a more simple approach to this question:
=>n^5-n is given to you.
So, on taking n common n(n^4-1) is you got.
so this expression has to be divisible by 5 the multiplication of both n and n^4-1 have to divisible by 5. And, Clearly for each number we have n^4-1 have to be divisible by 5.
Now, calling the number
Any number which has even in unit's place like 2,4,6,8
2^4=6
4^4=6
6^6=6
8^6=6
Any number which have even number in unit's place is leading to in 6 and subtracting 1 we got 5 so each expression is divided by 5
And, similarly for odd numbers 
1^4=1
3^4=1
7^4=1
9^4=1
And, subtracting 1 from we got 0 so it is again divisible by 5.
And, when we have 5 at unit's place n is divisible by 5.
Sorry , for the poor presentable form, but I think this will work

Comment: Also please let me know why it is down-voted and why this approach wouldn't work. And, someone should comment also explaining to the other community member why their approach is wrong.

Comment: I've no idea who downvoted your answer, but: (1) you didn't used LaTeX MathJax, making your post very hard to understand; (2) Some parts of the post are really obscure, to say the least, e.g. "calling the number Any number which *has even in unit's place* ...", "...place is leading to in 6...". At least you apologize at the end for the "poor presentable form", but I think that you should **really** enhance this if you want more people to read and understand your stuff.